# Why AND condition is not beeen checked?

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite

I'm implementing a sqlite3 query which is as follows:

```
NSString *searchQry=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id, title FROM ts_Gallary WHERE title LIKE '%%%@%%' OR location LIKE '%%%@%%' OR tags LIKE '%%%@%%' AND imageExistStatus = 1;",self.searchString, self.searchString, self.searchString];
```

All my OR conditions are working properly But AND part is not been Checked, as it return row which hane **imageExistStatus = 0** too.

And i'm unable to figure out the problem, so please help me with this.

Thank You.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1_____enAU376AU376&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=operator+precedence#sclient=psy&hl=en&rlz=1C1_____enAU376AU376&source=hp&q=sql+operator+precedence&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=6ab4216c4ada3168&biw=1200&bih=1835

Comment: You don't need all those percent signs, "%" is like ".*" in a regex so "%%%" is the same as "%".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, title FROM ts_Gallary WHERE (title LIKE '%%%@%%' OR location LIKE '%%%@%%' OR tags LIKE '%%%@%%') AND imageExistStatus = 1;
```

basically in your original query AND is applied only to `tags LIKE '%%%@%%'` condition.

Comment: Actually, "basically in your original query AND is applied only to tags LIKE '%%%@%%'" is difficult to understand, will you please elaborate..? :P

Comment: Without parentheses condition is evaluated as: title LIKE '%%%@%%' OR location LIKE '%%%@%%' OR (tags LIKE '%%%@%%' AND imageExistStatus = 1), because of operator precedence rules, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx